# How to read a specific cookie in the console

Tags: cookies, console, session-cookies

I know if I type document.cookie in the console I get all the cookies. But I only want to see the value of one cookie. How can I see the value of one cookie if the name of the cookie(key) is "UUID"?

THanks!

Comment: Did you googled "js cookies"??? You will get multiple examples wich you could easily change to fit into the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of a one-liner that will work.

`document.cookie.split('; ').filter(function(c) {return /UUID=/.test(c)})`

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do this in JavaScript. If you need to do it and are writing your own JS then you can write a function to handle the parsing, as document.cookie just returns a String that contains all the data.

This is a good implementation of a method to get a cookie by name.

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/getcookie/